# Does the order of matching columns matter when joining on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does the order of columns that are matched on matter?

1. First joining on code and then on id:

```
SELECT a.name, a.code, a.OBJECT_NAME, a.id, s.id_WANTED
    FROM table_1 a

RIGHT JOIN s ON
a.code = s.code
AND a.id = s.id_WANTED
```

2. First joining on id and then on code

```
SELECT a.name, a.code, a.OBJECT_NAME, a.id, s.id_WANTED
    FROM table_1 a

RIGHT JOIN s ON
a.id = s.id_WANTED
AND a.code = s.code
```

Comment: No, it doesn't matter.

Comment: SQL is declarative, not procedural, so the order shouldn't matter. If you do find a case where it does affect the final plan, it is purely happenstance.

Answer (score 0):

Short circuiting in a T-SQL `WHERE` clause is not guaranteed and cannot be relied upon, as the optimizer may choose to evaluate it however it wants ([see this Stack DBA question for a canonical answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/logical-operators-or-and-in-condition-and-order-of-conditions-in-where)).  Appreciate that we could actually write your query so that the `ON` clause logic appears in a `WHERE` clause (note: I *don't* recommend writing the query this way):

```
SELECT a.name, a.code, a.OBJECT_NAME, a.id, s.id_WANTED
FROM table_1 a, table_2 s
WHERE a.id *= s.id_WANTED AND
      a.code *= s.code;
```

Since we know there is no guaranteed order of operation in the above, therefore we can assume that joins behave this way.

Comment: I also recommend not writing the query that way, especially since this is a SQL Server question, not Oracle ;-)

Comment: @DanGuzman What is the SQL Server bad version of the OP's query?

Comment: I mean the example in your answer is using the proprietary Oracle non-ISO standard SQL syntax. The question is tagged sql-server so the SQL Server proprietary syntax (now discontinued) would be a.id `*= s.id_WANTED AND a.code *= s.code`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, because query engine would reorganize JOIN order depending on statistics for indexes and other things.
Add **OPTION (FORCE ORDER)** to the query and you will see that it matters.

AS a general rule of thumb, JOIN order should be with **table of least records on top**, and **the table of most records last**.So the performance would be much better.

Comment: The question asked about order of columns specified in join predicates, not the order of the tables.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have answered to the question and also mentioned the related things to the question asked.Thanks!